# how to customize facebook like button

Tags: facebook, plugins

I am usign the version of based on the <fb:like > tag. This renders a small facbook logo which implements the actual "like" operation, but also includes a large "signup to see what your friends like", or the number of likes when you are logged in, etc. It is pretty clear from what I have read that this is the form  facebook wants you to use, but it makes the button to wide for my layout. The point is that I see other versions on websites all over, in particular "the weather channel" has one that includes only the logo with some text such as "like us" next to it. "Chicago Tribune" has one that says "recomend" with a very small like count next to it. I have not been able to determine what these link to or what script they invoke so that I can copy them. Can anyone help ?

Comment: What the weather channel has is **not** the Like Plugin, it's just a button that open their Facebook Fan Page in a new window!

Answer (score 0):

when you get the code of the like button from facebook you can play with the options and get different results: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/.

obviously it's limited to how facebook wants it to look like.
it is possible to change the look with css, but that's not wise since it's against their policy and you'd have to keep track with their changes.